# cfspreadsheet causing variable undefined error

Tags: excel, coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I'm attempting to read a spreadsheet that has predefined charts on multiple tabs using cfspreadsheet, but when it comes to processing the data, I get variable is undefined.

I've used the example from Adobe - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html

I've also looked at other examples, but those examples use a combination of cfspreadsheet and poi or java and I would prefer to only use cfspreadsheet if possible.  Any idea looking at my code below where the problem is coming from?  Thanks.

```
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" reset="Yes">

<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="#request.dsn#">
SELECT *
FROM v_Occurrences
</cfquery>

<cfset strFileName = "OccurrenceData" & "#now().getTime()#" & "#UserID#">
<!---
<cfdump var="#GetData#">
--->

<cfset filepath = "file:///...OccurenceData.xls">
<!--- Write the two sheets to a single file --->
<cfspreadsheet 
    action  ="read" 
    columnnames = "Occurence_Date,Full_Name_Client"
    columns = "2"
        excludeHeaderRow = "false" 
    headerrow = "1"
    query="GetData" 
    rows    = "2"
    src ="#filepath#">  

<cfscript> 
    OccurrenceData = SpreadsheetNew("Data"); 
    Month = SpreadsheetNew("Month"); 
    Person = SpreadsheetNew("Person");  
    SpreadsheetAddRows(occurrencedata,getdata); 
</cfscript> 

<!--- Write the two sheets to a single file --->
<cfspreadsheet 
    action="write" 
    filename="#filepath#"
    name="OccurrenceData"   
    overwrite="true"
        sheetname="Data" > 


<cfspreadsheet 
    action="Update" 
    filename="#filepath#" 
    name="Month"
        sheetname="Month"> 

<cfspreadsheet 
    action="Update" 
    filename="#filepath#" 
        name="Person" 
        sheetname="Person" >

<cfspreadsheet 
    action="read" 
    src="#filepath#" 
    sheetname="occurrencedata" 
    query="GetData">
```

Here's where the error occurs: variable Occurrence_Data is undefined

```
<cfscript> 
    SpreadsheetAddRow(OccurrenceData,"Date,Name",1,1); 
    SpreadsheetAddRow(OccurrenceData, 
    "#Dateformat(Occurrence_Date,'mm/dd/yyyy')#,#Full_Name_Client#", 
    2,1,true); 
</cfscript> 

<cfspreadsheet 
    action="write" 
    autosize="true"
    filename="#strFileName#.xls"
    overwrite="true"
    password="password"
    query="GetData"
        sheetname="Data" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem number 1.  This is probably doing more harm than good.

```
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" reset="Yes">
```

Problem number 2.  If you want to write two sheets to a single file, you don't do this:

```
OccurrenceData = SpreadsheetNew("Data"); 
Month = SpreadsheetNew("Month");
```

You do something like this:

```
OccurrenceData = SpreadsheetNew("Data"); 
// do stuff with this sheet
SpreadsheetCreateSheet(OccurrenceData, "Month");
SpreadSheetSetActiveSheetNumber(OccurrenceData, 2);
// do stuff with this sheet

SpreadSheetWrite(OccurrenceData, whateverYourFileNameIs);
```

I also suggest that you do one thing at a time.  Write a bit of code, run it, and look at the results.  Then add a bit more code, run it, and look at the results.  This will help you isolate the code that causes the error.

Comment: So I adjusted my code and simplified it to the below and am not getting any errors, but I'm also not getting an excel sheet - just a blank screen.  I knew I needed to adjust the SpreadsheetAddRow line to loop my data so you can see the changes below:

    <cfscript> 
        spObj = SpreadsheetNew("Data"); 
        SpreadsheetAddRows(spObj,#getdata#); 
        SpreadsheetAddRow(spObj,"Date,Name",1,1);
        SpreadsheetCreateSheet(spObj, "Month");
        SpreadSheetSetActiveSheetNumber(spObj, 2);
    </cfscript>

Comment: <cfloop query="#GetData#">
    <cfscript>
        spObj = SpreadsheetNew("Data"); 
        for (i = 1; i <= GetData.recordcount; i ++) { 
         SpreadsheetAddRow(spObj,"#Dateformat(getdata.Occurrence_Date,'mm/dd/yyyy')#,#GetData.Full_Name_Client#",2,1,true); 
         }
    </cfscript>
    </cfloop>

    <cfscript>
        SpreadSheetWrite(spObj, "#filepath##strFileName#.xls","yes");
    </cfscript>